# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.StudentCrud.repository.StudentRepository1' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-11 10:36:45.161 ERROR 4668 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.StudentCrud.service.StudentService required a bean of type 'com.example.StudentCrud.repository.StudentRepository1' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.StudentCrud.repository.StudentRepository1' in your configuration.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question needs detail in order for someone to help you. Please read [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running this application in Eclipse. If yes, then you have to first run `mvn clean install` for eclipse to generate implementation of `CrudRepository`, then you should be able to run it.

Comment: yes i am using eclipse. you tell me where mvn clean